# Mockito Issue in mocking a list

Tags: java, mockito

I want to mock a list

```
private Item populateData(Item i) {
    List<Person> groupIdList = xyzDao.getData(id);
    for (Person p: groupIdList) {

    }
}
```

I want to testing the function by mocking groupIdList  how to perform this ?

Comment: Have you looked here: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html ?

Comment: @pcalcao : The link is dead. Can you please update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official Mockito documentation is a bit misleading. You should not mock list (data container without much logic), you should mock behaviours. In your case `xyzDao.getData(id)` is the behaviour. Mock `xyzDao` and return some bogus data:

```
//given
XyzDao xyzDaoMock = mock(xyzDao);
//inject to XyzService class under test
given(xyzDaoMock.getData(id)).willReturn(Arrays.asList(...));

//when
xyzService.populateData()  //...XyzService uses mocked XyzDao

//then
```

In *then* section you should either `verify()` that `xyzDao` was called or make sure correct list was returned. Hard to tell what you need based on your code snippet.

Comment: +1 for a fine answer.  Worth noting that if you're stubbing `getData()`, the return value that you're providing is probably used by something later in the test.  If it isn't, you wouldn't bother stubbing it; but if it is, then the condition that you're testing isn't going to come true if `getData()` doesn't get called.  So to keep your test simple, EITHER don't stub it, OR don't `verify` it - rely on some other assertion to prove that the value was used appropriately.  The only real reason to use `verify` for a method that you've stubbed is if you want to assert that it was called ONLY ONCE.

Answer (score 0):

Or the non-BDD version of Tomasz' answer (but accept his answer over mine, if appropriate):

```
XyzDao xyzDaoMock = mock(xyzDao);
when(xyzDaoMock.getData(id)).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(...));

xyzService.populateData()  //...XyzService uses mocked XyzDao
```